# Slide logo and text on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when you click on the menu button, a sliding animation is played on the logo and the text in the header.  Both of them are to slide left.  Menu slides out of screen and text slides in to screen to replace the logo's position.  In addition to that, a menu will drop down on the screen as demonstrated in the js fiddle below.

I've been trying for some time now to make this work but with no luck.  I have made a JS Fiddle to show what I have attempted: https://jsfiddle.net/n9tjvrjt/

The JS Fiddle contains a little more code than usual, I'm sorry about that but I felt all of that code there will be crucial in order for me to demonstrate my attempts.  I believe the key component is transition, but for some reason it just doesn't want to work.  The code I'm referring to is written below

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  html body .wrapper .header-wrapper .header-row .header-cell.header-profile {
    display: none;
  }
  html body .wrapper .header-wrapper .header-row .header-cell.header-profile.active {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -moz-transition: 3s;
    -o-transition: 3s;
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
    transition: 3s;
  }
  html body .wrapper .header-wrapper .header-row .header-cell.header-logo.active {
    position: absolute;
    left: -335px;
    -moz-transition: 3s;
    -o-transition: 3s;
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
    transition: 3s;
  }
}
```

As you will see in the fiddle, the code behaves exactly how I want it to, except the animation never plays.  I'm not sure why, any help is most appreciated.

Also, please ignore the long class names, it is coming from a sass file that was compiled for purpose of demonstrating the problem.

**Important note, please resize your screen to be under 670 pixels when testing the fiddle.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the transition for all:

```css
 html body .wrapper .header-wrapper .header-row .header-cell.header-logo.active {
    position: absolute;
    left: -335px;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Teuta, I have tried your example and on my browser it has no effect, it behaves just like mine.

Comment: Have you set all transitions to: all .2s ease-in? I have tried just using incpect element, cus there is to much code, and it worked for me.

Comment: yeah I have, its still super quick.  Its not slow at all.

Comment: @Bagzli, in css, everytime when you used left:-someValue in active class, try set left:0, in those elements that are not active.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, but the problem is that I also had to set position to absolute on them which broke my entire layout.

Comment: @ Teuta Koraqi, Thanks for fix. I have got same issue one of my snippet.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq, glad to hear that! Good luck! :)